# open media encoding standards

Tags: video-encoding, content-encoding

I have to choose methods for digitizing and encoding media for a project which collects media from a variety of sources.
What are the open media encoding standards I should consider?
What could be the factors which affect my decision on the selection of one?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things to consider, for example: platform, speed of encoding, what requirements your clients will meet (in terms of codecs), quality/size trade-off.  Take a look at [xvid](http://www.xvid.org/).  It's a free MPEG-4 video codec for PC.